# jQuery addClass for alternating levels of child elements

Tags: jquery

Say I have this html

```
<div class="details">
    <div class="details">
        <div class="details">
            <div class="details"></div>
            <div class="details"></div>
        </div>        
        <div class="details">
            <div class="details"></div>
            <div class="details"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Without knowing the number of levels i'll have, is there a way I can add a class to every other level?

This would be the desired outcome:

```
<div class="details">
    <div class="details alternate">
        <div class="details">
            <div class="details alternate"></div>
            <div class="details alternate"></div>
        </div>        
        <div class="details">
            <div class="details alternate"></div>
            <div class="details alternate"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT
I know such questions are frowned upon since it seems that I've not tried anything. But I have no idea what to look for

**UPDATE**
Updated the html to show that there could be multiple details divs on the same level

Comment: Could you give us an example of the result you're looking for? That HTML doesn't seem complete, by the way - the first `<div>` tag doesn't have a closing `</div>` tag.

Comment: example given. no idea why the last tag was being omitted when pasting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works, albeit putting the `alternate` class on the first level and subsequent odd levels, rather than second and even:

```
$('.details').addClass(function() {
    if (!$(this.parentNode).hasClass('alternate')) {
         return 'alternate';
    }
});
```

You could use this instead which marks both the even and odd levels:

```
$('.details').addClass(function() {
    return $(this.parentNode).hasClass('odd') ? 'even' : 'odd';
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/P4ggZ/2/

Comment: Marked as answer as others said that is was the most efficient

Comment: @MatthewGrima BTW, if you know you're on HTML5 you can make this even faster by replacing the test with the pure DOM test `this.parentNode.classList.contains('odd')`

Comment: I'm not, but that's nice to know

Answer (score 3):

You can use the number of `.details` parents each element has, and if it is an even number apply the `.alternate` class

```
$('.details').filter(function(){
    return ($(this).parents('.details').length % 2) === 0;
}).addClass('alternate');
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/Ltn2j/1/

Comment: +1 -- never occurred to me you could use [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents) this way.

Comment: Both your answer and Alnitak's work, not sure who to choose as the correct one.

Could anyone tell me which one is most efficient?

Comment: @MatthewGrima Mine works too. The prettiest and most readable is Gaby's one in my opinion. As for the fastest, if that really matters, you should run jsperf with some real HTML.

Comment: I think mine is most efficient, because it only requires a single consideration of `this.parentNode` for each element to test whether to add the class or not, and not the entire ancestry.

Comment: Indeed, @Alnitak's is more efficient for the test case, but it will not work if there are other elements between the `.details` elements (as containers) since it will break the assumption that `parentNode` is one..

Comment: There won't be any elements in between unless someone touches my code :)

Considering I have other javascript going other sections of the page, I'd take the most efficient. Thanks :)

Comment: @MatthewGrima fair enough :)

Comment: Upvoted your comment for effort and honesty though. Everyone gets a treat :P

Answer (score 1):

**1) pure CSS solution :**

I suppose your number of levels has a maximum, so you could use

```
body > .details { }
body > .details > .details { }
body > .details > .details  > .details { }
...
```

But this might get heavy if the style is big. In this case you'd better use a format allowing mixins to build your css (for example [less](http://lesscss.org/)).

**2) jQuery solution (following question edit) :**

If you want to do add a style in jQuery, you might do

```
function changeChilds($elems, depth) {
   if (!$elems.length) return;
   if (depth%2) $elems.addClass('alternate');
   changeChilds($elems.children('.details'), depth+1);
}
changeChilds($('body > .details'), 0);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ageweq/1/edit)

Comment: Logically, I don't have a maximum no, although I could assume... But I wouldn't like to assume.